# Value check in array.map() not working as it should in react render()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function

I have this Component

I map a prop of it and render some values

I have a method that returns the average of the values

My idea is ..  during the `map` function in the `render()` method .. to check on each iteration .. If the value is bigger than the average to give it a red color if is less give it green ... else give it the inherited color.

```
calculateAverageConsumption = () => {
      if (!this.props.fuelD) return 0;
      let sum = 0 , avr;
      for( let i = 0; i < this.props.fuelD.length; i++ ){
        sum += parseInt(this.props.fuelD[i].value);
      }
      avr = ( sum / this.props.fuelD.length ).toFixed(2);
      return avr;
  }
  colorOfvalues = (dataValue) => {
    let arg = this.calculateAverageConsumption();
    if(dataValue > arg){
      return "red";
    }else if ( dataValue < arg){
      return "green"
    }else return "inherit"
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Average: {this.calculateAverageConsumption()}</p>
        { this.props.fuelD.map((data , i )=>{
            return (
              <p key={i} style={{color: this.colorOfvalues(data.value) }}>date:{data.date}
              value:{data.value}</p>
            )
          }) }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Value check in array.map() not working as it should in react render
What I'm getting each time is either all get a red color or all get green color .. based on the

`( "<" and ">" sings )` ... Wath am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are `this.props.fuelD` and `this.calculateAverageConsumption()` value?

Comment: Can you provide a live example, with a data sample so we can see the issue ?

Comment: `this.props.fuelD` is an Array of objects ... from which I take only the value property which is a string parsed to number,... `this.calculateAverageConsumption()` returns the average of those values as a number

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake when I to this line of code

```
style={{color: this.colorOfvalues(data.value) }}
```

the data.value is a string pulled from the database ... to in the color method I compare a string to an integer

```
style={{color: this.colorOfvalues(parseInt(data.value)) }}
```

this works